# How to expose MongoDB documents primary keys in a REST API?

Tags: node.js, express, hapi.js

I am building a REST API with MongoDB + nodeJS. All the documents are stored and are using _id as the primary key. I've read [here](http://toddfredrich.com/ids-in-rest-api.html) that we should not expose the _id and we should use another ID which is not incremental.

In the DB, a document is represented as:

```
{ 
   _id: ObjectId("5d2399b83e9148db977859ea")
   bookName: "My book"
}
```

For the following the endpoints, how should the documents be exposed?

```
GET /books
GET /books/{bookId}
```

Currently my API returns:

```
{ 
   _id: "5d2399b83e9148db977859ea"
   bookName: "My book"
}
```

but should it instead return something like:

```
{ 
   id: "some-unique-id-generated-on-creation"
   bookName: "My book"
}
```

**Questions**

- Should I expose the _id so that one can make queries such as:

  GET /books/5d2399b83e9148db977859ea
- Should I use a UUID for my ID instead of ObjectId?
- Should I keep the internal _id (but never expose it) and create another attribute id which would use UUID or another custom generated ID ?
- Is it a good practice to work with _id in my backend or should I only make queries using my own custom ID? Example: find({ id:  }) instead of find({ _id:  })

Answer (score 4):

To answer your questions.

1. You can expose _id so that authenticated users can make queries like GET, PUT and PATCH on that _id.
2. MongoDB has support that allows you to generate your own BSON ID and use it, instead of mongodb created it's own _id during the insert.
3. There is no need of duplicating logic, the main purpose of _id is to identify each document separately and having two id columns means you are storing redundant data, follow DRY (DO NOT REPEAT YOURSELF) principle wherever possible.
4. It's not a bad practice to work with _id in your backend.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Given you're using Mongoose, you can use 'virtuals', which are essentially fake fields that Mongoose creates. They're not stored in the DB, they just get populated at run time:

```
// Duplicate the ID field.
Schema.virtual('id').get(function(){
    return this._id.toHexString();
});

// Ensure virtual fields are serialised.
Schema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true
});
```

Any time toJSON is called on the Model you create from this Schema, it will include an 'id' field that matches the _id field Mongo generates. Likewise you can set the behaviour for toObject in the same way.

You can  refer the following docs: 

1) https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html

2) [toObject method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toObject)

Comment: Thanks, I see some value in that. For instance dealing with BSON object sometimes cause errors especially when you compare ids, such as myObject._id == someObject._id

Comment: If you hve bson object , then you can convert bson object into json object using 'lean()' method

Answer (score 0):

In my case, whether it's a security risk or not, but my _id is a concatenation of any of the fields in my Document that are semantically considered as keys, i.e. if i have First Name, Last Name, and Email as my identifier, and a fourth field such as Age as attribute, then _id would be concatenation of all these 3 fields. It would not be difficult to get and update such record as long as I have First Name, Last Name and email information available

Comment: What if you update the name? Then the id change? It's seems a bit like the perfect recipe to create duplicate documents. And edge cases when there are no name, or age, etc.. Not sure this is a bullet proof method.

Comment: that is why I said it depends on what you consider as key(unchanging). if your app's use cases include a situation where typos can happen all the time or people makes name changes every now and then then names cannot be part of the key